# sqldeveloper importing currency formatted columns

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a delimited file with a column "cost" such as:
$140.89

sqldeveloper fails to import due to $ symbol in the input file. My table datatype is NUMBER. Is there a way to import the file without changing it, ie, removing the $ symbol from input file?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options if you want to use the SQL Developer import feature from say CSV or Excel

1. edit the data and remove the currency symbols (preferred)
2. change the column data type from number to varchar2

The data type change is the lazy man's way out, and will HAUNT you. Do the right thing and sanitize the data before it goes in.

There is a 3rd option.

Import the data to a temp table where the data is stored as a varchar2, and then do a INSERT AS SELECT from the temp table to the existing table, and do a substr() on cost to skip the 1st value, and the data should implicitly convert to a number.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I was able to accomplish it using sqlldr. here is the loader.ctl file in case someone else might be interested in this solution: load data
 infile 'mydata.txt'
 into table mytable fields terminated by "\t" optionally enclosed by '"' (COST "REPLACE(REPLACE(:COST,'$',''),',','')"

Comment: Sqlldr is the way to go if you know how to use it for sure, it will always be faster, but does really require an Oracle client install